# Can you use Firebase on a non-yet built mobile app?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tsx

I am planning to use Firebase for the backend of a mobile app project, and I was wondering : am I obligated to build an app to be able to use Firebase (e.g for tests) ? Or is there a way to use Firebase during my programmation phase ?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase offers about a dozen of services. Including databases and test tools.
You can use any subset of those services

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase any way you want using the provided APIs and SDKs.  This might or might not involve a mobile app.  As long as you stay within the limits of the free tier, or are willing to pay for the services you consume on the Blaze payment plan, nobody will care if you have an app or not.